# Proving the Archimedean property

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

Theorem. If $x>0$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$, then there is $n>0$ such that $nx>y$.

Is the following proof correct?

Proof. Suppose that $x>0$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\frac{y}{x} < \lceil{\frac{y}{x}}\rceil +1 $. Let $n = \lceil{\frac{y}{x}}\rceil +1$, which is a natural number. Then $\frac{y}{x} < n \Rightarrow y < nx$. QED

Comment: If you can prove the existence of ceiling function without using Archimedean Property, then the proof is okay. Can you prove?

Comment: @SuccessfulFailure One minor issue with your comment is that the OP is using the ceiling function, not the floor function. Also, the proof doesn't properly handle cases where $y \lt 0$ causes $n \le 0$ since the theorem statement requires $n \gt 0$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan can we solve the issue if we let $n = \lceil \left|\frac{y}{x} \right| \rceil +1$?

Comment: @JDMaximo What do you think? Note there are multiple possible ways to handle the issue of $y \le 0$. For example, you can just treat it as an initial case by saying that if $y \le 0$ then can just use any $n \gt 0$, e.g., $n = 1$, since $x \gt 0$ means $nx \gt 0 \gt y \; \to \; nx \gt y$, and then treat $y \gt 0$ as you've already done. Another way is to let $n = \max\left(1, \left\lceil{\frac{y}{x}}\right\rceil +1\right)$. It's up to you to decide how to best handle that issue based on aspects like keeping your proof relatively understandable, simple, straight-forward, elegant, etc.